# iOS High Rebase/Binding Time

Tags: ios, swift, startup, launch

I have been having some issues with my app taking longer than expected to launch, typically between 1.0 - 1.2 seconds. Particularly, the rebase/binding section of the pre-main app launch is taking up 66% of the launch time (around 790 milliseconds). I have tried looking at other threads such as [iOS slow startup time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388419/ios-slow-startup-time) and [How to debug slow app launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240399/how-to-debug-slow-app-launch). I am only using one library through CocoaPods which is called "JT Apple Calendar." How do I decrease my pre-main app launch time to be within Apple's standards (400 milliseconds)?

*Note: I am using Swift if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

The launch time depends on a lot of parameters but it will often depends of the size of your app and your code.
You can read this [article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/slow-app-startup-times/) which will explain you the startup process.

I have tested an empty project with JTAppleCalendar and the startup times before and after are very close so it don't come from this I think. It comes certainly from your code, read the article and try to figure it.

You can also check this WWDC session for more information: [WWDC 2016 Session 406 Optimizing App Startup Time](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/)